# Special search in tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-routing, url, research

How can I search in tor browser and get only .onion URLs?
Because right now it jut like a normal search engine but with hiddenwiki what makes it just a little bit better than Chrome.

Comment: [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/19302/5234) may be interesting for you... especially starting with number 5. resp. 6.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ahmia.fi](https://ahmia.fi) does the thing. It indexes Tor sites by his own algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a search engine that searches onion services. You can find some [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/) or [here](https://github.com/alecmuffett/real-world-onion-sites). Once you find a search engine that you want to use, right-click on the search bar and choose "add keyword for this search".

This is the exact same as Firefox. See [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/114176/how-to-easily-create-search-plugins-add-any-search-engine-to-your-browser/) for more information.